# ERROR:make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, make, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I attempted to use the "Linux-Kernel-Module-for-Listing-Tasks" from GitHub (https://github.com/TheRealYoussef/Linux-Kernel-Module-for-Listing-Tasks/blob/master/ListTasksLinear.c) on Ubuntu running on the Windows Subsystem.

After completing the step `sudo apt install make`, I encountered an error while compiling with `make`:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2/build M=/home/<user>/ospro

make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.

make: *** [Makefile:7: all] Error 2
```

I executed the command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-generic
```

and

```
sudo apt search linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Result:

```
Sorting... Done

Full Text Search... Done
```

If I executed the command:

```
ll /lib/modules
```

Result :

```
total 12

drwxr-xr-x  .....
```

How can I fix this?